# Regex replace character before copying the text block

Tags: regex

Given the following Regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\[?]?(.+)?$
```

I need to add a character if the second block it condition is true (´?´exists).

Example:

```
myapp/test/urltofollow?name=john&age=36
```

Result:

```
1.  [0-22]  `myapp/test/urltofollow`
2.  [22-39] `?name=john&age=36`
```

And What I need:

```
1.  [0-22]  `myapp/test/urltofollow`
2.  [22-39] `&name=john&age=36`
```

The **?** shall be replaced to **&** only if **?** exists, so:

```
myapp/test/urltofollow
```

Must result:

```
1.  [0-22]  `myapp/test/urltofollow`
2.  [22-39] `` (empty)
```

Comment: It is not possible to return from regexp match anything that is not present in the original string. If you need to make a replacement in one of the capture groups, you need to deal with it in further code (which we can't supply, given that the only tag you gave is [tag:regex]). Note that regular expressions themselves are *only* for searching, even if languages that implement them often have functions that also replace the matches yielded by the regexp.

Comment: This will be used on usr.rewrite (lighttpd)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very knowledgeable about lighttpd, but this might work:

```
url.rewrite-repeat = ( 
  "^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)(\?(.+))?$" => "http://example.com?foo=bar&$3",
  "^(http://example.com?.*)&$" => "$1"
)
```

Basically, just add an ampersand and the parameters to the new URL anyway (without the question mark); if the new URL ends up ending with the ampersand, strip it.

Comment: That does not exactly work, but gave me a path to solve the problem. I did two rules, one if I have the `?`char (url call with parameters) and another rule if I don´t have the `?` (url call with no parameters). Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Good. :) Also, most backends will not at all be fussy about urls with extra ampersands: `http://example.com/?foo=bar&&&&&` will be treated exactly the same as `http://example.com/?foo=bar`. So you only really need two rules if you are doing a client-side redirect, for prettiness. Just the rule #1 in my (failed) attempt should be sufficient for the overwhelming majority of server-side redirects.

Comment: I know about that. Extras ampersands makes no difference at all... Please upvote question if you think is valid.